# Holes in 2D circle collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to begin new game development that has rotating circle that has one or many holes as in the attached image , the problem is I need to use circle collides for the big circle., in addition I need to use small collides for the smaller holes to prevent and particles(smaller circles ) input the circle and to count no of collisions occurred
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAB7T.png)

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What difficulties have you experienced? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I would use a `PolygonCollider2D` then check if the distance from the collision point is smaller than the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

The circle collider itself does not have this functionality since it can only check collisions between perfect circles. (Behind the scenes all circle colliders just check the distance between points and these distances do not work with holes) The best solution I can think of would be to use a polygon collider and make a rough circle that you can then remove parts of (would require some advanced geometry but not impossible). I have tried simillar things in 3D and with the mesh collider, removing parts of it using a method known as CSG ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)) and something simillar should be possible in 2D however **it is really, really hard** and even experienced programmers struggle to come up with a system that can handle every scenario.

All hope is not lost though, depending on what you need the collision for, there might be other ways. If you just need to check if two objects intersect and don't want rigibodys and stuff to interact with the collider just checking the distance between the big circle and the object (too figure out if it's close enough) and then checking the distance between the object and the holes (too see if it's inside a hole on thus not colliding) is the best way to solve the issue.

I'm sure someone who have done more in this field than I have will be able to help you out but without more information of what you need it's impossible to say. It all depends on the circumstances!